# circular reference error in NodeJS/MongoDB code

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working on sample application using Node JS , Express , MongoDB , and to access MongoDB from NodeJS am using native mongodb drivers for nodejs.
Below is part of the code which is giving me problem.

```
 module.exports.getLookups = wrap(function * (req , res) {
 let users = yield getUsers();
 db.close();
 res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 res.send(JSON.stringify(users));
});

// get users from MEAN mongoDB
function * getUsers(){
 return db.collection("users").find({});
}
```

"res.send(JSON.stringify(users));" line instead of returning json data , it is throwing circular reference error. "users" collection is a simple collection with few records. Please let me know if more info needs to be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collection.find()` returns [a Cursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#find). If you want to read all the results from that cursor, you should call [`.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Cursor.html#toArray) on it:

```
function getUsers(){
 return db.collection("users").find({}).toArray();
}
```

(`getUsers()` doesn't have to be a generator function)

Comment: Yes , you are correct , getUsers need not be generator.